# How can I make a PHP class instantiate another class in its constructor?

Tags: php, oop

I'm so kind of new here and in PHP.

I want to know what's the right way to instantiate a class in another class constructor within his parameters.

(I have some shit test in the botton)

```
class CryptoControl {

    public $helper;
    public $keyValues;

    public function __construct ($primo1, $primo2, $message) {
        $this->helper = new MathHelper();
        $this->keyValues = new KeyValues($primo1, $primo2, $message);
    }

    public function criptografa_descriptografa_simetrica() {

        $message = $keyValues->getMessage();
        echo "Texto original: " . $message . "\n";
        echo "Chave criptografada: " . base64_encode($message) . "\n";
        $message_criptografada = base64_encode($message);
        echo "Chave descriptografada: " .    base64_decode($message_criptografada) . "\n";
    }
}

$exec = new CryptoControl(17, 41, "TURING");
$resposta = $exec->criptografa_descriptografa_simetrica();
echo $resposta;
```

And that's the class that I'm wanting to instantiate:

```
class KeyValues {

    public $numeroPrimo_1;
    public $numeroPrimo_2;
    public $message;

    public function KeyValues ($primo1, $primo2, $message) {
        $this->numeroPrimo_1 = $primo1;
        $this->numeroPrimo_2 = $primo2;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    #getters and setters
 }
```

That's the error that I'm getting...

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: keyValues in /home/rodolfolottin/gitrepositories/Crypto/CryptoControl.php on line 72
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getMessage() on a non-object in /home/rodolfolottin/gitrepositories/Crypto/CryptoControl.php on line 72

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the following line

```
$message = $keyValues->getMessage();
```

to

```
$message = $this->keyValues->getMessage();
```

`$keyValues` inside a method in a class refers to a local variable. When you access with `$this` keyword then it refers to a property of object of that class.

Answer (score 0):

```
class KeyValues {

    public $numeroPrimo_1;
    public $numeroPrimo_2;
    public $message;

    public function KeyValues ($primo1, $primo2, $message) {
        $this->numeroPrimo_1 = $primo1;
        $this->numeroPrimo_2 = $primo2;
        $this->message = $message;
    }
    public function getMessage() {
        return $this->message;
    }

    #getters and setters
 }


class CryptoControl {

    public $helper;
    public $keyValues;

    public function __construct ($primo1, $primo2, $message) {
        $this->helper = new MathHelper();
        $this->keyValues = new KeyValues($primo1, $primo2, $message);
    }

    public function criptografa_descriptografa_simetrica() {

        $message = $this->keyValues->getMessage();
        echo "Texto original: " . $message . "\n";
        echo "Chave criptografada: " . base64_encode($message) . "\n";
        $message_criptografada = base64_encode($message);
        echo "Chave descriptografada: " .    base64_decode($message_criptografada) . "\n";
    }
}

$exec = new CryptoControl(17, 41, "TURING");

$resposta = $exec->criptografa_descriptografa_simetrica();

echo $resposta;
```